# How to replace mismatch values in unix

Tags: unix, awk

I am comparing two files using unix Awk

```
col_1,col_2,col_3
1,2,4
1,3,6

col_1,col_3,col2,col_5,col_6
1,2,3,4,5
1,6,3,,,
```

Below is the code i am using

```
awk '
NR == FNR       {if (NR == 1)   for (MX=n=NF; n>0; n--) REF[$n] = n
                 else           TMP[NR] = $0
                 next
                }

FNR == 1        {for (n=NF; n>0; n--)   {if ($n in REF) CMP[n]=REF[$n]
                                         if ($n == SRCH) NSR = n
                                         HD[n]  = $n
                                         NL     = "Null"
                                        }
                 next
                }

                {n = split (TMP[FNR], IT)
                 EQU = 1
                 for (i=1; i<=MX; i++)  {T = IT[CMP[i]]
                                         if ($i != T)   {print SRCH, $NSR ": mismatch at", HD[i] ":", $i?$i:NL, "-", T?T:NL
                                                         EQU = 0
                                                        }
                                        }
                 if (EQU) print SRCH, $NSR, "doesn´t have any mismatch."
                }


' FS="," SRCH="col_1" file2 file1  # comparison files
```

I need to replace the mismatch records based on file2, can some one please guide

Comment: So what's expected output, based on what condition ?

Comment: I would like to get below output  col_1,col_2,col_3
1,4,3
1,3,6

Comment: please explain how, what you are trying to do

Comment: the logic of matching is unclear

Comment: Hi guys, Iam trying to compare the two csv files based on col_1 as primary key column and comparing each rows based on the columns. If i find any mismatch then i will print that and now i wanted to replace the mismatched record from file_2

Comment: Please update the expected output and matching logic to the question.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==1   {n1=split($0,cols1);h=$0;next} 
                    NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} 
                    FNR==1  {print h; n2=split($0,cols2); 
                             for(i=2;i<=n2;i++) cols[cols2[i]]=i; next} 
                    $1 in a {for(i=1;i<=n1;i++) 
                               printf "%s%s", 
                                      $(cols[cols1[i]]),(i==n1)?ORS:OFS}' file1 file2


col_1,col_2,col_3
1,3,2
1,3,6
```

your second file column header has a typo.